# Provided og:image url encountered an unknown error

Tags: facebook, azure, facebook-graph-api

Yesterday I attempted to share a web page on Facebook, specifically https://share.novamanus.com/ad/659, however this did not preview correctly on Facebook. When I attempted to scrape this with the Facebook Open Graph Debugger I saw an error I've not encountered previously.

```
Provided og:image url, https://novamanusprod.blob.core.windows.net/nmphoto/thumb_aa76caf4-f394-402a-a84a-58124222b6b4.jpeg encountered an unknown error.
```

There was no additional information elaborating about what was going on. The response from the web page was HTTP 200.

[image]

I could at the same successfully access the image url directly, but attempts to re-scrape the page with the Facebook Open Graph Debugger resulted in the same error message.

What could possibly be causing this? 30-40 minutes after this attempt everything worked perfectly. I've not been able to reproduce the issue thus far, nor has Azure blob storage logs told me anything.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @UnSaid Sadly no, this was a one time thing and I've not experienced anything like it since.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
For my case, it was due to the size/resolution of the image, I have downsize it, and it worked!

Comment: @UnSaid what image size solved the problem for you?

Comment: 2256 × 1128 has worked for me, 

Here's what I've found on FB https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images
but It doesn't specify what is the maximum size ...

Comment: I encountered this same problem and it was automagically fixed about 10 minutes later--must be something to do with FB caching (as mentioned in several other SO posts).

Answer (score 5):

I've encountered this same error and I checked the docs.

According to the documentation it recommends:

> 3. Optimize images to generate great previews
>      Image Sizes
>      Use images that are at least 1080 pixels in width for best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 pixels in width to display image link ads. We recommend using 1:1 images in your ad >creatives for better performance with image link ads.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Since adding an image which has the minimum width of 1080px width this resolved my problem.

Comment: Making the image 1,200 pixels wide and 628 pixels tall did the trick for me. Looks like if the image was too large, it will be a problem as well. Not 100% sure...

Comment: @OctaviaLo this was the only thing that worked for me... silly facebook! Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem recently and I fixed it by uploading a smaller file (about 1024px wide, 72dpi ~ 100kb), it worked. I had to open the Facebook debugger and ask it re-scape the page.

Answer (score 0):

I know it may sound dumb but it did work for me, most propably your photo format was PNG, change it to JPG and it should be fine.

Comment: It was a JPG image with a jpeg extension, so not PNG.

Answer (score -3):

It solved by

```
<meta property="og:url" content="FULL_PAGE_URL" />
<meta property="og:image" content="FULL_IMAGE_PATH" />
```

Comment: This question is five years old. The Facebook framework has likely changed many times since the original question was posted. The original issue is most likely not reproducible any more and there may be a ton of reasons why it didn't work and why it now works. Using the meta tags you have specified here is probably not what would have solved my original problem.

Comment: may be, but my problem was solved with this... so I have shared it.